# Is it possible to use STL objects in c ++ code of native extension for dart?

Tags: c++, c, dart, stl

I tried to describe in the module sample_extension.cc ( *https://www.dartlang.org/articles/server/native-extensions*) STL string:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string string_ ("std.string");
```

and that was enough for the shared library *libsample_extension.so* to stop being created. Maybe any special rules for creating such libraries or is there a more serious problem? For now, I use the commands:

```
g++ -fPIC -DDART_SHARED_LIB -c sample_extension.cc
gcc -shared -Wl, -soname, libsample_extension.so -o libsample_extension.so sample_extension.o*
```

and no errors messages.

I get an error later at the command line on run dart:

```
$ dart test_sample_synchronous_extension.dart
libsample_extension.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error: library handler failed
```

Comment: What with the spaces in `-Wl, -soname, libsample_extension.so`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"enough for the shared library libsample_extension.so to stop being created"*? If you are getting error then you should post it here.

Comment: @VTT, I get an error later at the command line on run dart:

    $ dart test_sample_synchronous_extension.dart
    libsample_extension.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error: library handler failed

Comment: It does not mean that libsample_extension.so is not created, it means that dart is not able to find it.